# Muscular involvement in psychological constipation

Tags: musculoskeletal-system, nervous-system

Is the underlying physiology of constipation based in the voluntary muscles (eg levator ani tensing, holding the rectum closed), or is it an effect of the slowdown of the digestive system with an increase in sympathetic nervous system activity?  In a recent discussion, both sounded plausible but I have not been able to find solid information one way or the other.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "psychological constipation"?

Comment: Constipation due to stress or similar psychological factors, as opposed to opioid use or other physiological factor.